# Reserve app name ios

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm trying to reserve a name for an app on iOS store. Does anybody know if it's necessary to upload an binary of the app before the name is reserved? I've uploaded all the basic info and screenshots of the design, but I'm not in the progress of creating the app yet..

Comment: I dont have any reference docs to show, but from my experience , its enough just to create an app from iTunes connect. It is not necessary to upload a binary

Comment: I'm trying to do so, but it keeps giving me when trying to 'submit the app for review' and points to the "upload a build' section

Comment: Go through this article , its 5 months old but i believe nothing has changed after that. http://blog.salsitasoft.com/apples-new-app-name-reservation-policy/

Comment: @BhumitMehta Is this still true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you create a new app in iTunesConnect and have a valid developer account (which you have, otherwise you couldn't create the app) the app's name is reserved for you. You don't have to do any further request or something, the creation is enough.

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: Can't really tell tbh. Maybe try to create an app that already exists to figure it out, such as "Instagram" (given it's spelled exactly like this).